# Error on Pay with Amazon Extension

Tags: payment-methods, amazon

I have integrated Pay with Amazon payment module and getting error while redirect to amazon site.

**Below is the error messages:**

> We're sorry!
>   An error occurred when we tried to process your request. Rest assured, we're already working on the problem and expect to resolve it shortly.
>
> **Error Summary**
>   400 Bad Request - The redirect URI you provided has not been white-listed for your application

Comment: redirect is on https ? Amazon requires this

Comment: Yes, we have enabled SSL..

Comment: I have also added header on server <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>

Comment: Check from the amazon side, may be theie can be some error with your account or misconfiguration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to white list your domain in seller central. Log in, select Login with Amazon from the drop down at the top of the page. Once there, populate your domain in the "Allowed JavaScript Origins section. Also add the return URL you specified to allowed return URLs.

Comment: Yes, i am able to resolved this issue..I have defined store url in amazon seller account..

Comment: hi abhishek, i have the same problem, i am using amazon pay in localhost. how to test amazon on localhost. ? What should i define "Allow javascript"  under websetting. thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `http://localhost` for allowed javascript origins. The "localhost" entry does not require a certificate (https). You can also include a port if your local web server is running on a non-standard one. e.g. `http://localhost:3000`.